# How to map a command to multiple edits

Tags: vim

I'm using the plugin [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), which maps ds( to "delete surrounding brackets", e.g. turns (Hello) into Hello. I want to map a command to delete a function appliction, e.g. turning foo(bar) into bar.

I tried

```
nmap <Leader>df bdt(ds(
```

to go to the beginning of the word, delete up to the first (, and then delete the surrounding parentheses. However, when I use it, it only deletes up to the bracket, and doesn't do the subsequent deletion of the brackets themselves. I've tried putting other editing commands after the initial part, and that works. So

```
nmap <Leader>df bdt(x
```

works as expected.

Similarly, I tried just doing

```
nmap <Leader>s ds(
```

and that also works!

Other things that don't work:

```
nmap <Leader>df bdt(<bar>ds(
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a simpler mapping like the following.

```
nmap <silent> dsf ds)db
```

This will delete the "surrounding" function application so the cursor needs to be on or inside the parens.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful mapping, and I can report that changing my other mapping to `bdt(ds)` made it work. Not quite sure why, though.

Comment: `b` moves back to the beginning of a function, so on the `f` in `foo(bar)`. `dt(` will will til the `(`. The cursor on the `(` and `ds)` will delete the surrounding parenthesis. The main difference between our two mappings is in your mapping the cursor must be on the function name or `(`.

Answer (score 0):

Another one, supposing the cursor is somewhere in the parentheses:

```
nnoremap <leader>df yi(B"_df)p
```

- `y`ank what's `i`nside the parentheses
- jump to the `B`eginning of `function`
- `d`elete the whole function call in the black hole register
- `p`ut the previously yanked text